# CSS Animations on pseudo element background

Tags: html, css

I'm using this codepen example to create a full page fade out using pseudo element, however its a bit jarring in this form as it just appears, id like to fade it in and out with CSS3 animations, but when I try to apply them to the CSS none of them work, the only thing i an get working is the transition delay.

http://codepen.io/css-tricks/pen/dxyfA

```
#login {
z-index: 2;
}
#login:after {
content: "";
position: fixed;
top: 0;
left: 0;
right: 0;
bottom: 0;
background: rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
z-index: -1;
pointer-events: none;
}
#login:hover:after {
z-index: 1; 
background: rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
}
```

Can anyone figure out how to get the background the element to fade in to an opaque white?

Comment: I just added `transition: background-color 1s linear;` to the after element and it seemed to do the trick, are you looking for anything more complicated than that?

Comment: Can't believe thats the only one I didn't try, duh! Thanks! The only extra thing I like to do is fade out when mouse off, where can I place the transition to do that? Putting it into the hover doesn't work.

Comment: It should handle both directions without putting it anywhere else. When you say fade out, you mean background colour or something else?

Comment: Background colour back to transparent - i'm going to assume it doesn't "fade" back to that because as soon as you mouse away from the element the zindex makes it disappear - can we fade z-indexs?

Comment: Hmmm getting rid of the z-index seems to be the way forward and just make the after background element transparent.

Comment: I would use opacity rather than z-index, then it's a simple tweak to the transition. Though technically you could transition the z-index, and use a delay to make it happen after the colour changes. Edit: Or as you're using RGBA, just a transparent background as you said.